# How to concatenate string and noneType object

Tags: arcgis-10.2, labeling, python-parser, concatenation

My issue is:

I can't concatenate string and noneType object. Some attribute values are empty. It follows that label isn't displayed.

What is the solution?

```
def FindLabel ( [CONTENU], [NOM_OBJET_USUEL] ):
  if [CONTENU] == u"Eaux usées":
    return "<CLR red='168' >" + [NOM_OBJET_USUEL] + "</CLR>"

  elif  [CONTENU] == u"Eaux mélangées":
    return  "<CLR red='168'  >" + [NOM_OBJET_USUEL] + "</CLR>"

  elif [CONTENU] == "Eaux pluviales":
    return  "<CLR green='77' blue='168' >" + [NOM_OBJET_USUEL] + "</CLR>"

  elif  [CONTENU] == "Eaux de drainage":
    return  "<CLR green='77' blue='168' >" + [NOM_OBJET_USUEL] + "</CLR>"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If for example `[NOM_OBJET_USUEL]` contains empty values, replace all occurences with `([NOM_OBJET_USUEL] if [NOM_OBJET_USUEL] else "")`

This replaces NoneType with an empty string.